# Mysql-Empty query error in last updated row php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I cannot see an answer to my question after hours of searching online.
Trying to obtain id of last updated row. This is my php script-

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","DB_NAME","PWD");  
if (mysqli_connect_errno())  
  {  
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
  }  
mysqli_select_db($con,"DB") or die ("no database");   


$result=mysqli_query($con,"SET @update_ID := 0;  
UPDATE TABLE_234 SET PLAYERNAME = PETER, ID = (SELECT @update_ID := ID)  
WHERE PLAYERNAME IS NULL  
LIMIT 1;  
SELECT @update_ID ");

if (!mysqli_query($con,$result))  
  {  
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));  
  }  

echo $ID;  
mysqli_close($con);
```

The error-
Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in… on line…
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near…

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**
you try to show $ID within last lines; but where did you set it in php code?

try this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","DB_NAME","PWD");  
if (mysqli_connect_errno())  
{  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
}  
mysqli_select_db($con,"DB") or die ("no database");   
$sql="SET @update_ID := 0;  
    UPDATE TABLE_234 SET PLAYERNAME = PETER, ID = (SELECT @update_ID := ID)  
    WHERE PLAYERNAME IS NULL  
    LIMIT 1;  
    SELECT @update_ID as ID";

if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
  do
    {
    // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con))
      {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {

        $ID=$row[0];
        }
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}

echo "ID=" . $ID;  
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Using your code, I get-
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE TABLE_234 SET PLAYERNAME = PETER, ID = (SELECT @update_ID :='  at line 2.
Don’t know what is wrong…

Comment: we have to use mysqli_multi_query, so answer edited, try again

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `mysqli_query` twice in your code.  The first way is the correct way, the second way is wrong.  In the first call you are passing SQL string, however in the second call you are passing result.

Based on your code, I believe you want to check `$result` in the `if` statement as follows:

```
if (!$result)  
{  
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My problem appears to occur above that statement; here-
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE TABLE_234 SET PLAYERNAME = PETER, ID = (SELECT @update_ID :='  at line 2.
Don’t know what is wrong…

Comment: That problem is because you are trying to execute multiple sql statements with `mysqli_query`. You need `mysqli_multi_query`.  Have a look at documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","DB_NAME","PWD");  
if (mysqli_connect_errno())  
{  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
}  
mysqli_select_db($con,"DB") or die ("no database");   
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SET @update_ID := 0;  
    UPDATE TABLE_234 SET PLAYERNAME = PETER, ID = (SELECT @update_ID := ID)  
    WHERE PLAYERNAME IS NULL  
    LIMIT 1;  
    SELECT @update_ID ");

    if (!$result)  
    {  
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));  
    }  

    echo $ID;  
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE TABLE_234 SET PLAYERNAME = PETER, ID = (SELECT @update_ID :='  at line 2. Any ideas?